# Quick detection of lost Kafka nodes on lost network

Tags: apache-kafka

We are running Kafka in a 3 node setup with Kafka and Zookeeper on each node. The topics have 1 partition and 2 replicas, like:

```
Topic:someTopic    PartitionCount:1    ReplicationFactor:2    Configs:retention.ms=600000
    Topic: someTopic    Partition: 0    Leader: 2    Replicas: 2,0    Isr: 2,0
```

We uses the following settings

Consumer settings:

```
fetch.min.bytes=1
enable.auto.commit=true
max.partition.fetch.bytes=1073741824
```

Producer settings:

```
metadata.fetch.timeout.ms=1000
```

If we stop Kafka and Zookeeper on one node with 'kill -9', Kafka detects that the leader is missing within seconds and switches leader to the other replica and consumers will continue to receive messages.

If we on the other hand bring down the network for the same node with 'ifdown eth0' (which will break the connection to both Kafka and Zookeeper on that node) it seems like Kafka have problems detecting that the broker is missing and it takes up to 2 minutes until any more messages can be consumed on affected topics.

The following log can be seen on the consumer :

```
[2017-05-04 15:44:26,916] WARN Auto offset commit failed for group console-consumer-75510: Commit offsets failed with retriable exception. You should retry committing offsets. (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator)
```

and on the producer:

```
May 04 15:44:18: 15:44:18.420 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-2] ERROR - app Publishing to topic 'someTopic' failed
May 04 15:44:18: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.NetworkException: The server disconnected before a response was received.
May 04 15:44:18: 15:44:18.435 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-2] ERROR - app Publishing to topic 'someTopic' failed
May 04 15:44:18: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.NetworkException: The server disconnected before a response was received.
May 04 15:44:18: 15:44:18.440 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-2] ERROR - app Publishing to topic 'someTopic' failed
May 04 15:44:18: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.NetworkException: The server disconnected before a response was received.
May 04 15:44:18: 15:44:18.442 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-2] ERROR - app Publishing to topic 'someTopic' failed
May 04 15:44:18: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.NetworkException: The server disconnected before a response was received.
May 04 15:44:18: 15:44:18.444 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-2] ERROR - app Publishing to topic 'someTopic' failed
May 04 15:44:18: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.NetworkException: The server disconnected before a response was received.
May 04 15:44:18: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Batch containing 31 record(s) expired due to timeout while requesting metadata from brokers for someTopic-0
May 04 15:44:18: 15:44:18.446 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-2] ERROR - app Publishing to topic 'Heartbeat.Heartbeat' failed
May 04 15:44:18: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Batch containing 31 record(s) expired due to timeout while requesting metadata from brokers for someTopic-0
May 04 15:44:18: 15:44:18.448 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-2] ERROR - app Publishing to topic 'Heartbeat.Heartbeat' failed
May 04 15:44:18: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Batch containing 31 record(s) expired due to timeout while requesting metadata from brokers for someTopic-0
May 04 15:44:18: 15:44:18.449 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-2] ERROR - app Publishing to topic 'Heartbeat.Heartbeat' failed
```

... will continue print those for a while

Is there any way to make Kafka detect and rebalance when a node is down due to lost network as if Kafka is just killed